# tag synonym request: [sqlldr] - [sqlloader]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

"sqlldr" is the executable name for the Oracle *SQL*Loader* component.

Both tags are used interchangeably on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

While not intentionally sought-out, I did this as a by-product of the https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012#comment359303_128315.